# Plot data on pie chart using database in canvasjs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, canvasjs

I am using `canvasjs` I want to plot data from `database` into pie chart. I am able to get data from `DB` and pass it to an array.

`array_push($dataPointskWh, array("label"=>$pr['name'],"y"=>$cr['sum_kwh_diff']));`

**JS**

```
<script>
  var arry_kwh = [];
  arry_kwh = <?php echo json_encode($dataPointskWh, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>;
  console.log(arry_kwh);

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer2", {
        animationEnabled: true,
        title: {
            text: "Last Month Floor Wise kWh"
        },
        data: [{
            type: "pie",
            //startAngle: 240,
            //showInLegend: true,
            yValueFormatString: "##0.00\" kWh\"",
            indexLabel: "{label} {y}",
            dataPoints: [
              // here I want to add the data points
            ]
        }]
    });
    chart.render();
```

The `console.log(array_kwh)` gives me

```
0:
label: "Floor-1"
y: 1297

1:
label: "Floor-2"
y: 7.7
```

How can I plot them? Also, the data would increase so I want to plot in that way.

Comment: hi did you tried below answer ? did that work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your `label` and `y` data which you get from `arry_kwh` to some array and passed this array to your `dataPoints` to plot the values in graph.

**Demo Code** :

```js
//your data
var arry_kwh =[{
"label": "Floor-1",
"y": 1297
},{
"label": "Floor-2",
"y": 780}];
var dataPoints =[];
//loop through the array and add value to dataPoints array
$.each(arry_kwh , function(key, value){
        dataPoints.push({ y :value.y , indexLabel : value.label});
    }); 
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer2", {
        animationEnabled: true,
        title: {
            text: "Last Month Floor Wise kWh"
        },
        data: [{
            type: "pie",
            yValueFormatString: "##0.00\" kWh\"",
            dataPoints:dataPoints //passing values 
        }]
    });
    chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>

<div id="chartContainer2" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
```